# Polymer paper-swatch-picker how to change Icon

Tags: polymer-1.0, web-component, color-picker

Using the polymer `paper-swatch-picker`, I'm trying to change an icon but it is not getting updated.

In the below there is the CSS code which I have used to change icon. Is it correct?

HTML:

```
<paper-swatch-picker class="fancy"></paper-swatch-picker>
```

CSS:

```
paper-swatch-picker.fancy {
      --paper-swatch-picker-color-size: 10px; -- works
      --paper-swatch-picker-icon-size: 40px; -- works
      --paper-swatch-picker-icon: {
          'icon':'menu' -- not works(icon not getting changed)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attributes `icon` to change it instead of CSS. But you need to import the `iron-icons/iron-icons.html` first, according to the set you use. In this case, you are using `menu` icon, which belongs to the default set `iron-icons.html`. For example, `maps:...something` will belong to `iron-icons/maps-icons.html`

```
<base href="https://raw-dot-custom-elements.appspot.com/PolymerElements/paper-swatch-picker/v2.2.0/paper-swatch-picker/">
<script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="paper-swatch-picker.html">
<link rel="import" href="../neon-animation/web-animations.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<style>
  paper-swatch-picker {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
</style>
<!-- Customized color swatch -->
<paper-swatch-picker icon="menu" color="#E91E63"></paper-swatch-picker>
```

I have also written an article featuring the top color picker web components, including paper-swatch-picker as well. Here's the [link](https://vaadin.com/blog/best-color-picker-component-l2t-paper-color-vs-paper-swatch-picker-vs-color-picker) if you want to read.